# How much information/access could the owner of the router and Internet connection have (using his Wi-Fi with his permission)—and how to stop it?

Tags: wifi, internet

I just moved to a new apartment/room and I'm using my roommate's brother's Wi-Fi connection (almost 3 times faster and 3 times cheaper than if I would get my own Internet). He has access to the router.

1. How much information could the owner of a connection/router—if moderately knowledgable—access (i.e., check in the settings or actually hack) regarding...

   - Online banking?
   - Websites visited?
   - Email?
   - Passwords?
2. Can an owner of a connection/router—again, if moderately knowledgable—hack your computer and get access to your files?
3. If not, what would be the level of difficulty, when owning the router, be to get access to the above mentioned information/files?
4. What protection would make sure that everything mentioned above—banking info, websites visited, passwords and files—would almost be 100% unaccessible (when using someone elses Intenet connection, with his permission, and he has access to the router)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I prevent my neighbors, whom I pay for shared internet (wifi), from seeing the sites I've visited?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/), [Renting a bedroom in a house with shared wifi, how to secure myself?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68924/), [How to find out if somebody is spying on my private browsing data in the same WiFi network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8662), [Do VPNs provide sufficient protection over public wireless networks?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18049/).

Comment: You are essentially asking about how to protect yourself when using a network you cannot trust. It does not matter if this is a public hotspot provided by some company or a private access point provided by a person you know but not fully trust. The answer usually is: use a VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your roommate's brother has the intent to spy on you and he has some basic computer and networking knowledge...

By performing a man-in-the-middle attack with the right tools he could easily see which websites you've visited by capturing your DNS queries. He could also capture other sensitive information. For example, if you visited insecure websites over HTTP or if you choose to ignore the following warning during a website spoofing attack:
[image: Your connection is not private (Google Chrome screenshot)]

It is also worth mentioning that these types of attacks don't require direct access to the router.  Anyone on the LAN could perform this attack.

Since you do not **trust** the users of this wireless network, treat it as if you are using public WIFI and ***use a VPN***.